# Insufficient Permissions with Access Token to Azure Data Catalog

Tags: authentication, token, access-token, azure-data-catalog

I'm trying to issue an API call to Azure Data Catalog using a Client Secret, however I get a Permission denied error.

I'm able to create the token and I've given the client application the necessary permissions in AAD.

If I change the authentication method to use delegated access where the user signs in, it works but if i try to use a client secret the generated token does not have the proper permissions.

Here's some code that I've altered using various samples

The token from this code works

```
//get the token

authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));

//the token from this code doesn't work

IConfidentialClientApplication app;

app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authorityuri))
                .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com/.default" };

result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);
```

I get this error The remote server returned an error:

> (403) AccessDenied : Access denied..

Answer (score 1):

Following is high level steps to configure the Service Principal configuration to support ADC REST API

- Azure Active Directory | App Registration – Select Web app / API for Application Type and URL can be anything Example:  http://portal.azure.com
- Select the Application | Required Permission | Add the Microsoft Azure Data Catalog
- Navigate to http://www.azuredatacatalog.com | Settings - Add the Service Principal to Catalog User based on the business need you can add to glossary admin / catalog admin.     The format is clientid@tenantid

****Clientid = Azure Active Directory | App Registration | Application ID**

**TenantID = Azure Active Directory | Properties | Directory ID****

- Follow the Service Principal Authentication sample REST API code to build your solution  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-catalog-dotnet-service-principal-get-started